# twine: warning: `long_description_content_type` missing

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py, pypi, twine

This is what my setup.py looks like:

```py
from distutils.core import setup

setup(
    author='...',
    description='...',
    download_url='...',
    license='...',
    long_description=open('README.md', 'r').read(),
    long_description_content_type='text/markdown',
    name='...',
    packages=['...'],
    url='...',
    version='...'
)
```

Then, I can run `python setup.py sdist` without any errors. But if I check the package with twine (`twine check dist/*`), I get the following warning:

```
 `long_description` has syntax errors in markup and would not be rendered on PyPI.
  warning: `long_description_content_type` missing. defaulting to `text/x-rst`.
```

All of my packages are up to date, and I have no duplicate or multi-line attributes. What is causing this, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're using the setup function provided by `distutils.core`. Use `setuptools` instead:

```py
from setuptools import setup
```

`distutils.core` doesn't expect the `long_description_content_type` to be provided, and seemingly ignores it. It actually says this when you run setup.py:

```
UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'long_description_content_type'
```

Although that's easy to miss, since it's at the top of a long block of otherwise error-free logs.